# VHDL error XST:1426

Tags: vhdl

I would like to implement a Finite State Machine in VHDL but I've 2 warnings that appears :

```
 WARNING:Xst:1426 - The value init of the FF/Latch FFd6 hinder the constant cleaning in the block FSM.
   You should achieve better results by setting this init to 0.

WARNING:Xst:1426 - The value init of the FF/Latch FSM_FFd6 hinder the constant cleaning in the block FSM_0-parent.
   You should achieve better results by setting this init to 0.
```

If I understand, I think that the problem come from the Init of the state :

```
-- State machine
type state_type is (    idle, 
                            pga_load, sendBitPGA, clockHighPGA,
                            catchADC, setADC
                            );

signal state : state_type := pga_load;  --  First state of the State Machine is PGA_LOAD
```

But I don't know hot to change the code to avoid that warning...

Can someone help me?

Comment: My experience is that this warning doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, so it's impossible to remove this warning?

Comment: Have you tried to exchange the position of  idle and pga_load in the definition?

Comment: @Botnic
I just try it but unfortunately it doesn't change anything...

Comment: In design summary, click "Synthesis Messages". Find the warning, right click it, and select "Filter all instances of this message".

Comment: Thank you ! Where can I see this warning again now? Is it possible to do the reverse operation? (just for my knowledge)

Comment: Ok, I just have to clic on "Show Messages filtered", thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is displayed, when the logic for 'state' can be optimized to a constant value from the behavioral description and if this constant value than differs from the specified initial value.

Just take a look at this smaller example which leads to the same warning:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity constant_cleaning is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           y : out  STD_LOGIC);
end constant_cleaning;

architecture Behavioral of constant_cleaning is
    type states is (idle, running);
    signal state : states := idle;
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            state <= running; -- constant value differing from initial value
        end if;
    end process;

    y <= '1' when state = running else '0'; -- just some output
end Behavioral;
```

If this is the intended behaviour, then just ignore or filter the warning.